# Is there a tested way of chatting with WLM contacts in-game while playing Forsaken World?

Tags: forsaken-world

Is there a tested way of chatting with WLM contacts in-game while playing Forsaken World?

Comment: Alt+Tab? No, seriously, there is no other way.

Comment: Well, XFire doesn't support Forsaken World just yet. I was wondering if there are any available options.

Comment: I think your question isn't clear enough... Are you seeking a way to easily discuss with friends without minimising FW? You should try using Steam, by adding FW as a non-steam game. This way, you should be able to chat with your friends through the steam overlay.Though, it does require you and your friends to have a Steam account (it's free, since you don't need any steam games to possess an account). By the way, you should edit the question to make it clearer, you would have more specific comments.

Comment: I did clearly mention that I wanted WLM (Windows Live Messenger) contacts. =) So, a solution requiring my friends to sign up for something doesn't qualify. Just like XFire does it, I'd like to have an overlaid window where I can chat with my WLM contacts just like yet another multi-protocol IM client. Unfortunately, XFire doesn't support Forsaken World just yet. So, yes, that's all.

Comment: I don't remember any 3rd-party software which provide an overlay function for another 3rd-party software... But since it could be really usefull,  i think someone already programmed it. I'll try to search a bit...

Comment: It seem's [Gamepe](http://www.gamepe.com/) could be what you're looking for... (I'm at work ATM, i'll check later to be sure and maybe submit as an answer)

Comment: If only Valve came through on their promise of providing XMPP and an API for the Steam overlay...

Answer (score 1):

As said earlier, maybe you could give a try to [Gamepe](http://www.gamepe.com/), which does provide an overlay for WLM (*and IRC*) while IG.

This software is currently in beta, so it may not be the most stable solution, but since the only alternative i saw to this was another beta software, which is no longer supported (and was abandoned for several years), this one seems to be the more serious possibility...

Answer (score 0):

You can run in window mode, which will give you the ugly borders. But you can also run in window mode and use [this little program I made](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16862782/RemoveTitleBar.exe). Type in your resolution in the lower part and hit the checkbox, select the game window in the upper part and click the left button in the lowest part. Sorry it's not English, but what it does is remove the title bar and make the window be "fullscreen". It also currently does not work on 64 bit Windows because of some int64 pointers, bleh ;)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing i could come up with is http://raptr.com/ Though i dont know if they have an working overlay for your game i know they do support WLM.

Gl trying stuff